# An RL circuit excited by an impulse voltage source

Tags: transient

According to my textbook when an impulse voltage source is connected in series to a resistor and an inductor the impulsive voltage appears directly across the inductor and there is no voltage drop across the resistor. I don't understand why?

Comment: Circuit theory rule #27: Current through an inductor can not change instantaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are starting with no current.

Inductors resist change in current.

An "Impulse" (suddenly/quickly applied) voltage will, initially, be face with an inductor which has been happily sitting at no current, so there will be (initially) no current, so there is no voltage drop across the resistor. Depending on the length of the impulse and the value of the inductor, this will change over time.